# Error deploying Qt Quick Application to Jolla Phone: nothing provides libQt5Qml.so.5

Tags: c++, qt, sailfish-os

Created the default Sailfish OS Qt Quick Application and used Deploy to build the rpm. When I try to install the `rpm` on the phone, I see this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libQt5Qml.so.5(Qt_5) is needed by harbour-xxx
```

`libQt5Qml.so.5` is provided by `qt5-qtdeclarative` package which is installed on the phone and the libraries are present in `/usr/lib/`.

Am I missing something in packaging the `rpm` or is there something I need to setup on the phone to deploy the application?

**Edit:**

.yaml file contents which generates the rpm. (edited for brevity)

```
PkgConfigBR:
    - sailfishapp >= 1.0.2
    - Qt5Core
    - Qt5Qml
    - Qt5Quick

Requires:
  - sailfishsilica-qt5 >= 0.10.9
```

Generated .spec file (edited for brevity)

```
Requires:   sailfishsilica-qt5 >= 0.10.9
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(sailfishapp) >= 1.0.2
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(Qt5Core)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(Qt5Qml)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(Qt5Quick)
BuildRequires:  desktop-file-utils
```

Comment: Does your `rpm` include `libQt5Qml.so.5`?

Comment: I have added the yaml file contents and the generated spec file from which the rpm is generated.

Comment: Had you allowed the library in your configuration? https://github.com/sailfishos/sdk-harbour-rpmvalidator/blob/master/allowed_libraries.conf

Comment: I'm unable to find allowed_libraries.conf anywhere either in ~/SailfishOS/ or ~/.config/SailfishOS-SDK/. I have just installed the vanilla Sailfish SDK and IDE. I know it runs the rpmvalidator as part of the deploy process, but I'm unable to find where these configuration files are.